# OpenSSL and CAPI - collisions in certificates

Tags: ssl, openssl, certificate, collision

I am running into collision problems with the CAPI engine for OpenSSL: In a normal case, I am able to use a private key stored on my smartcard to establish a SSL connection using OpenSSL. Simplified code:

```
    EVP_PKEY pkey = ENGINE_load_private_key(my_engine, subject_name, 0, 0);
    void * pdata = my_certificate_context.pbCertEncoded;
    X509 * cert = d2i_X509(0, &pdata, my_certificate_context.cbCertEncoded);
    SSL_CTX_use_certificate(my_ssl_context, cert);
    SSL_CTX_use_private_key(my_ssl_context, pkey);
```

There is, however, a catch: If it happens that I have more than one certificate with the given Subject Name, the CAPI engine will select one of the certificates and it's up to luck whether it selects the correct one. Fortunately for me, it selected the wrong one and this way alerted me to the problem. Looking at the source codes, it looks like the CAPI engine supports more complex key-searching schemes, so that I could specify that the Subject Name is supposed to be found in a specific certificate store. I can get the certificate store's name easily since I have the proper PCCERT_CONTEXT, but I can't figure out how to tell the CAPI engine to use that certificate store. The documentation is extremely sketchy here and I failed to find a single example. I expect it can be done using FENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string, but I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research and testing, I can conclude that it is possible to specify the location of the certificate in a bit more detail using **ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string**:

```
if (!ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(Engine, "store_name", "MY", 0)) printf("Failed!");
if (!ENGINE_ctrl_cmd_string(Engine, "store_flags", "1", 0)) printf("Failed!");
```

The first line tells the CAPI engine to use a different certificate store (in this case, "MY", but any other store such as "ROOT" can be used instead). The second line instructs the engine to use the local computer storage rather than current user one.

However:

1) Both of these values are global for the engine. If multiple simultaneous connections with different settings need to be used, each connection must have a separate engine. Which, contrary to what is written all over the net, **is** probably possible using the **SSL_CTX_set_client_cert_engine** function. In this case you **don't** need to set the engine as default for anything. (Note: I need to do some testing of what actually happens if I use two engines with different settings for two simultaneous connections. So far it looks like it will work, but I am not certain.)

2) It is not possible to specify other store locations such as the current service store. That will require an updating of the CAPI engine.

3) It is not possible to specify a certificate using a more precise identification, e.g. by specifying the hash or the serial number.

4) It is pointless to specify a certificate anyway, because the SSL engine will ignore such specification (and indeed anything done using the **SSL_CTX_use_certificate** and **SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey** functions). Instead, when a handshake is being performed, it will open the store specified by the command strings and search for a certificate signed by the CA chosen by the server. I am not sure what happens if multiple such certificates are found, I suspect a dialog is presented to the user. In any case, it is not possible to choose a specific certificate through code, unless you want to modify the engine's plugin. (Note: This may not be the case if you intend to use the certificates server-side.)

5) It is not only pointless, but in fact dangerous to use functions **SSL_CTX_use_certificate** and **SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey**, because the latter one WILL select the first matching certificate (e.g. with the same Subject Name) in the store and use it, regardless of the issuing CA or anything else.

This information is valid for the 1.0.2 branch of the OpenSSL. I didn't do any tests with either the newer or the older branches.